# Set default values form cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'd like to set a default value for two fields in my Users table.
Users table is like that :
`Users(id, role, name, username, password, active)`
I have a `add()` function in my UsersController to register new user. Here is the form :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
<br />
<?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
<br />
<?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
<br />
<?php echo $this->Form->button('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Role and active aren't here because I want to set their values by default. A new user can't choose his role and if he's active or not.
My `add()` function :

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //$this->data['User']['role'] = 'customer';
        //$this->data['User']['active'] = 1;
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('User registred.');
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => '/'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
}
```

How can I set these values before create a user, or update it? I tried to do it with save() but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: You should use `$this->request->data`. Try it with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['User']['role'] = 'customer';
        $this->request->data['User']['active'] = 1;
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
           $this->Session->setFlash('User registred.');
           return $this->redirect(array('action' => '/'));
        } else {
           $this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Asbolutely, thanks! It worked with `$this->request->data`

Answer (score 0):

May be your should be  like this?

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data = $this->request->data;
        $data['User']['role'] = 'customer';
        $data['User']['active'] = 1;
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('User registred.');
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => '/'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
}
```